# Animate scroll to anchor on load

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor

Im trying to animate past the purple block and to the header on load

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/stxsh/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="block">
block</div>

<div id="header">
Header</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#block {
    background: #342A7E;
    color: white;
    height: 200px;
}
#header {
    background: #3DB84E;
    color: white;
    height: 400px;
}
```

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
     $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: -200}, 1000);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/nSbjB/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 200}, 1000);
});
```

Comment: This doesnt actually have any effect :(

Comment: if yes.. on which browser you are running this..?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a bonus:

Dealing with performance, you might want to use objects animation:

```
var start = {v:0},
    end = {v: 200},
    duration = 10000,
    stepFunction = function stepFunction(v) {
        window.scrollTo(0,v);
    };

$(start).animate(end, {
    duration: duration,
    step: stepFunction,
    complete: stepFunction
});
```

which is a roughly 30% more efficient, this percentage being higher on ancestral browsers.

There you can still identify the initial scrollTop, with jQuery, or with properties described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scrollX).

Finally, you may experiment native setInterval or setTimeout methods, but it might mean running into problems since there are several methods to handle framerates.